# [C]: When a pointer to a pointer to a struct is passed in a function, why can't it change the elements of that struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

```
struct Node {
int data;
struct Node *next;
};

void insertAfterHead(struct Node **a, int x) {
struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
newNode -> data = x;
newNode -> next = *a -> next;
*a -> next = newNode;
}


int main() {
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    struct Node *second = NULL;
    struct Node *third = NULL;

    head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    third = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head -> data = 5;
    head -> next = second;

    second -> data = 10;
    second -> next = third;

    third -> data = 15;
    third -> next = NULL;

    insertAfterHead(&head, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error message I get on running the code:

error: member reference base type 'struct Node *' is not a structure or union
        newNode -> next = *a -> next;

error: member reference base type 'struct Node *' is not a structure or union
        *a -> next = newNode;

Please be as descriptive as possible as I'm a beginner to C :)

Comment: The error message is not corresponding to the code. And paste it here, not as an image but as a text.

Comment: Please post your output (error message) as text, and please post the error message you got from the code you posted (not from some other code).

Comment: In this case, there's no need to pass a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh.
Sorry, I renamed the variables (for clarification) while asking. Added error message too.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - Yes but I forgot the context in which I wanted to ask this so I made it up :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*headRef->next
```

means

```
*(headRef->next)
```

but you want

```
(*headRef)->next
```